# android add subtitle to mp4 with ffpmeg

Tags: ffmpeg, android

I'm using ffmpeg with Android. I want to burn an SRT file (subtitle) into my MP4. My code is:

```
ffmpeg -i /sdcard/AddSrtToVideoTemp/video.mp4 -i /sdcard/AddSrtToVideoTemp/video.srt -c:s mov_text -c:v copy -c:a copy /sdcard/AddSrtToVideoTemp/new.mp4
```

The code compiles successfully but the subtitles are not added to new.mp4.

My console output is:

```
ffmpeg version N-69972-g6c91afe Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
     built with gcc 4.9 (GCC) 20140827 (prerelease)
    ffmpeg4android 2.5_24p6_full_no_x264 
      libavutil      54. 19.100 / 54. 19.100
      libavcodec     56. 25.100 / 56. 25.100
      libavformat    56. 23.100 / 56. 23.100
      libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
      libavfilter     5. 11.100 /  5. 11.100
      libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
      libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
      libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
     Splitting the commandline.
     Reading option '-i' ... matched as input file with argument '/sdcard/AddSrtToVideoTemp/video.mp4'.
     Reading option '-i' ... matched as input file with argument '/sdcard/AddSrtToVideoTemp/video.srt'.
     Reading option '-c:s' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'mov_text'.
     Reading option '-c:v' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'copy'.
     Reading option '-c:a' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'copy'.
    Reading option '/sdcard/AddSrtToVideoTemp/Video_11611173526.mp4' ... matched as output file.
    Finished splitting the commandline.
    Parsing a group of options: global .
    Successfully parsed a group of options.
    Parsing a group of options: input file /sdcard/AddSrtToVideoTemp/video.mp4.
    Successfully parsed a group of options.
    Opening an input file: /sdcard/AddSrtToVideoTemp/video.mp4.
    Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 probed with size=2048 and score=100
    ISO: File Type Major Brand: isom
    rfps: 29.916667 0.008074
    rfps: 29.916667 0.008074
    rfps: 30.000000 0.000128
    rfps: 30.000000 0.000128
    rfps: 60.000000 0.000511
    rfps: 60.000000 0.000511
    rfps: 120.000000 0.002045
    rfps: 120.000000 0.002045
    rfps: 240.000000 0.008182
    rfps: 29.970030 0.001565
    rfps: 29.970030 0.001565
    rfps: 59.940060 0.006258
    Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 5610022 bytes read:35643 seeks:1
    All info found
    After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 73704 bytes read:109315 seeks:2     frames:48
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from /sdcard/AddSrtToVideoTemp/video.mp4:
Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isom3gp4
    creation_time   : 2016-10-12 22:23:37
  Duration: 00:00:04.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 11189 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng), 1, 1/90000: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661),  yuv420p, 1280x720, 12229 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.79 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn,  180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 180
      creation_time   : 2016-10-12 22:23:37
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
      encoder         :                                
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of 180.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(eng), 47, 1/48000: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-10-12 22:23:37
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
    Successfully opened the file.
    Parsing a group of options: input file /sdcard/AddSrtToVideoTemp/video.srt.
    Successfully parsed a group of options.
    Opening an input file: /sdcard/AddSrtToVideoTemp/video.srt.
    Format srt probed with size=2048 and score=100
    Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 167 bytes read:167 seeks:0
    All info found
    After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 167 bytes read:167 seeks:0 frames:0
    Input #1, srt, from '/sdcard/AddSrtToVideoTemp/video.srt':
    Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0, 0, 1/1000: Subtitle: subrip
    Successfully opened the file.
    Parsing a group of options: output file  /sdcard/AddSrtToVideoTemp/Video_11611173526.mp4.
    Applying option c:s (codec name) with argument mov_text.
    Applying option c:v (codec name) with argument copy.
    Applying option c:a (codec name) with argument copy.
    Successfully parsed a group of options.
    Opening an output file: /sdcard/AddSrtToVideoTemp/Video_11611173526.mp4.
    Successfully opened the file.
    Output #0, mp4, to '/sdcard/AddSrtToVideoTemp/Video_11611173526.mp4':
    Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isom3gp4
    encoder         : Lavf56.23.100
    Stream #0:0(eng), 0, 1/90000: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p,  1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 12229 kb/s, 29.79 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k  tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 180
      creation_time   : 2016-10-12 22:23:37
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
      encoder         :                                
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of 180.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(eng), 0, 1/48000: Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz,  stereo, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-10-12 22:23:37
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
    Stream #0:2, 0, 1/1000: Subtitle: mov_text ([8][0][0][0] / 0x0008)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.25.100 mov_text
    Stream mapping:
    Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
    Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
    Stream #1:0 -> #0:2 (subrip (srt) -> mov_text (native))
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    Delay between the first packet and last packet in the muxing queue is 3242975044 > 10000000: forcing output
    Delay between the first packet and last packet in the muxing queue is 11245000 > 10000000: forcing output
    No more output streams to write to, finishing.
    frame=  108 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    5480kB time=00:54:15.24 bitrate=  13.8kbits/s    
    video:5413kB audio:63kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB  muxing overhead: 0.076349%
    Input file #0 (/sdcard/AddSrtToVideoTemp/video.mp4):
    Input stream #0:0 (video): 108 packets read (5542944 bytes); 
    Input stream #0:1 (audio): 188 packets read (64171 bytes); 
    Total: 296 packets (5607115 bytes) demuxed
    Input file #1 (/sdcard/AddSrtToVideoTemp/video.srt):
    Input stream #1:0 (subtitle): 4 packets read (16 bytes); 4 frames decoded; 
    Total: 4 packets (16 bytes) demuxed
    Output file #0 (/sdcard/AddSrtToVideoTemp/Video_11611173526.mp4):
    Output stream #0:0 (video): 108 packets muxed (5542944 bytes); 
    Output stream #0:1 (audio): 188 packets muxed (64171 bytes); 
    Output stream #0:2 (subtitle): 4 frames encoded; 4 packets muxed (24 bytes); 
    Total: 300 packets (5607139 bytes) muxed
    4 frames successfully decoded, 0 decoding errors
ffmpeg4android: 0
```

Comment: Your command line seems fine to me. Notice that your ffmpeg console output shows: `Output stream #0:2 (subtitle): 4 frames encoded; 4 packets muxed (24 bytes);` are you sure you are using a correct .srt file? (which contains actual content?)

Comment: @ir.appstudio I just tested your code on a piece of video. It works magnificently. So, probably the reason you think the subtitle is not added is because the app with which you try to watch the video doesn't support the subtitle format. I tried PotPlayer in Windows. To isolate the problem I advise you to do the same.